# Angular.js - Attaching DOM items from the model

Tags: angularjs

I am learning Angular and am getting json data externally.

If parts of the data come back undefined or blank I want to hide the certain element on the page.

How can you do this from the model?

I am doing all my logic from the model so it seems against programming practice to then do an if statement in the controller to validate undefined data to attach it to an ng-show or a hide css class?

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Make use of angular expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check ngShow & ngHide documentation
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="angular.isDefined(item.value)">
...
</div>
```

This only shows an item when value attribute is defined

Comment: I don't think `angular` object would be directly available on `html` directly..you need put that in a scope first..